# SQL query to find the table name

Tags: php, mysql

I have 5 different tables in my dB with the structure `Name|Price|Id..`

I have a unique price and Id entry combination.

Using these 2, what could be the possible SQL query to fetch the name of the table in which this entry is present?

I need to fetch the name of this table in order to update the value of Price.

Comment: Why do you have 5 different tables with the same structure in the first place?

Comment: this is because each of these tables denote a product say tea , coffee etc and the entries of each table (rows) a different brand of each of the product

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't use a single table with a `productname` column, and eliminate all the issues (such as this) that you get with 5 different tables

Comment: That is because each of these tables are already predefined as per the Android app being developed and any alterations to the DB structure can severely affect the overall system.

Comment: So basically, you've gone too far to rectify a bad design, so you need kludges to work round the issues that it creates

Comment: exactly!! this is my doubt... TableTea with attributes: Name|Brand|Id with entries Name=a|Brand=abc|Id=100, Name=b|Brand=xyz|Id=200 and another table Tablecoffee with attributes:Name|Brand|Id with entries Name=c|Brand=efg|Id=400, Name=d|Brand=lmn|Id=300. In a PHP page I am only aware of the Id=100 and Brand=abc (do not know the table in which this entry is present as the PHP page is passed via forms),then how can i find out the name of this table and thereby update the value of price to 500 in this table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your DBMS is MySQL you can use this Query:

```
SELECT Result.TABLE_NAME FROM (
  SELECT  TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,COUNT(*) AS QTA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
  where  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'NAME_DB'
  and COLUMN_NAME IN ('Name','Price','Id')
  GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
 ) as Result
WHERE Result.QTA = 3
```

i have already tried to do without php

**Replace NAME_DB with your Database.**

Comment: this doesn't tell whether or not a specific entry exists in the table.

Comment: ok this is my doubt... TableTea with attributes: Name|Brand|Id with entries Name=a|Brand=abc|Id=100, Name=b|Brand=xyz|Id=200 and another table Tablecoffee with attributes:Name|Brand|Id with entries Name=c|Brand=efg|Id=400, Name=d|Brand=lmn|Id=300. In a PHP page I am only aware of the Id=100 and Brand=abc (do not know the table in which this entry is present as the PHP page is passed via forms),then how can i find out the name of this table and thereby update the value of price to 500 in this table

Answer (score 1):

You really should normalise your database properly and use a single table, but if you really need a kludge then:

```
SELECT name, brand, id, 'Tea' as tablename
  FROM TableTea
 WHERE brand = 'abc'
   AND id = 100
UNION
SELECT name, brand, id, 'Coffee' as tablename
  FROM TableCoffee
 WHERE brand = 'abc'
   AND id = 100
UNION
SELECT name, brand, id, 'Chocolate' as tablename
  FROM TableChocolate
 WHERE brand = 'abc'
   AND id = 100
```

And you'll have to change it if you ever add new products

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to know the tables in which it's possible to have the entry.  Use a loop to iterate over those tables and run the query, each time returning a result set and testing if records exist in the result set.  This will tell you what tables have the entry.

General Approach:

```
$array = array("table1", "table2", "table3", "table4", "table5");
foreach($array as $table) {
    //build your query using the table name
    $query = "SELECT something FROM " .  $table;
    //exec your query against your db and return results
    //test if records exist in result set.  If true, you know the table name based on the loop iteration ($table).
}
```